# Random char stream choose uniform distribution

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

Ok another ridiculous daily code problem with an absurd answer

Q:
Given a stream of elements too large to store in memory, pick a random element from the stream with uniform probability

A:

For the base case where `i = 0`, let’s say the random element is the first one. Then we know it works because

For `i = 0`, we would’ve picked uniformly from `[0, 0]`.

For `i > 0`, before the loop began, any element `K` in `[0, i - 1]` had `1 / i` chance
of being chosen as the random element. We want `K` to have `1 / (i + 1)` chance
of being chosen after the iteration. This is the case since the chance of having
being chosen already but not getting swapped with the ith element is
`1 / i * (1 - (1 / (i + 1)))` which is `1 / i * i / (i + 1)` or `1 / (i + 1)`

The code:

```py
    import random
    
    def pick(big_stream):
        random_element = None

        for i, e in enumerate(big_stream):
            if i == 0:
                random_element = e
            elif random.randint(1, i + 1) == 1:
                random_element = e
        return random_element
```

So the `1/(k+1)` if you're still in a loop it's just `1/k` this elif `1/(k+1)` with the `I+1` seems artificial and wouldn't affect the `O(n)` time and instead make it `O(n+1)` which is the same as `O(n)`.

What really is meant by this question? This algorithm seems really superficial, is there any suggestions that really can beat `O(n)`? This programming language looks perlesque but it's not what language would be close to it? Is there a more optimal (more specific) language for this?

Answer (score 1):

The programming language (once the indentation is fixed) is most definitely Python.

> What really is meant by this question? This algorithm seems really superficial, is there any suggestions that really can beat O(n)?

This question is mostly about *space*, not *runtime*. The algorithm they provide runs in constant space, which was the point. The naive answer would use an enormous amount of space.

There is a simpler (not necessarily faster) algorithm however, which can also be used to sample `k` elements from `n` elements in `O(n log k)` time and `O(k)` space. It works like this:

> Assign an uniformly random real value in [0, 1] to each element from the stream as you receive it. Using a min-heap, keep track of the `k` smallest random values and their associated elements. Once the stream is fully processed return the elements that remain in the heap.

Which for `k = 1` simply becomes:

> Assign an uniformly random real value in [0, 1] to each element and return the element with the smallest random value.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of the algorithm described by @orlp for `k=1`:

```py
import random

def pick(big_stream):
    choice = None

    minp = 1.0
    for e in big_stream:
        p = random.random()

        if p >= minp:
            continue

        minp = p
        choice = e

    return choice
```